# CloseHandle для INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, c, winapi, handle

Если функция `CreateFile` вернула `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, нужно ли закрывать его функцией `CloseHandle`?

Comment: Не нужно. Теоретически всё что не запрещено - разрешено, правда ф-ция CloseHandle скорее всего вернет False или тоже invalid handle т.к. нечего закрывать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[В документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) прямо написано, что аргументом функции должен быть валидный дескриптор.

> **Pameters**
>
> *hObject* [in]
>
> A valid handle to an open object.

Answer (score 6):

Просто по логике - а *что* вы собираетесь закрывать? `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`? так он не соответствует никакому открытому файлу. У вас просто *нечего* закрывать.

Так что - нет, не нужно.